# Sigma Notation in Python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, sum

I am trying to create a sigma sum in python.

I have a 100 by 100 matrix (created with numpy) and I have a list of 100 values.
My matrix is the variable A, and my list is the variable Network.

The sum should look like so.

```
hi= Sigma( (A[i][j])* Network[j])
```

i and j in the matrix refer to the specific value, and j in Network refers to the value in the list.

so, if I wanted h67, the sum would be:

```
(A[67][67]*Network[67]) + (A[67][66]*Network[66]) + (A[67][65*Network[65]) + ...
(A[67][0]*Network[0]).
```

My code is as follows, but I don't think it is right.

```
def new_sum(i,j):
    hi=0
    hi+= numpy.sum((A[i][j]*Network[j]))
    return hi
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like this instead of using Numpy.sum() function?

```
def new_sum(i,j): 
    hi=0
    for n in range(j+1):
       hi+= A[i][n]*Network[n]
    return hi
```

The numpy sum() function just return the sum of all the elements in an array. The parameter you are giving to it is just a case and not an array to sum. So you are returning the sum of one element : this element.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a vector product followed by a sum along the resulting array. You could do something like this:

```
sigma = lambda x, y: np.sum(np.dot(x,y))

hi = sigma(A, Network)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a dot product.  I don't think you need to pass two indices to your function.  Also, you weren't looping in your original code, so there was no reason to initiallize hi to zero or use `+=`.  Finally, you need to return `hi`, not `sum`.

```
def new_sum(i):
    hi = numpy.sum(numpy.dot(A[i][:i], Network[:i]))
    return hi
```

**EDIT**

More better programming tips:  It is advisable to not use globals in a function, but pass the variables you need to the function, like this:

```
def new_sum(matrix, vector, i):
    return numpy.sum(numpy.dot(matrix[i][:i], vector[:i]))

# Now I can call this with ANY variables
hi = new_sum(A, Network, 67)
```

Note that in the function it is unnecessary to save the hi variable as well because it can be returned directly.